# Preventing UITableView updating when UITableViewCells scroll off the screen

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make a UITableView to display a label, UISegmentedControl, and UITextField on each tableview cell.  Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UISegmentedControl *phase = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    NSString *currentPhaseString = [[_data objectForKey:@"phase"] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", indexPath.row + 1]];
    int currentPhase = [currentPhaseString floatValue];

    [phase setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentPhase] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [phase setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentPhase + 1] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [phase setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];

    name.text = [[_data objectForKey:@"players"] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", indexPath.row + 1]];
    return cell;
}
```

The problem is when the user scrolls down and back up, any changes to the cells that got scrolled off the screen do not get saved. Is there any way to prevent the cells from recreating when the user scrolls them off the screen and back on? Thanks!

Comment: That would completely defeat the purpose of reusable cells. Instead, you should look into ways of saving the information after the user changes it.

Comment: The changes that the user makes should be saved in the data source that you use to populate the cells. You should have a key in a dictionary, or a property of an object, to keep track of the text field's text, and the segmented control's state.